# How does one get a handle / details for a window inside RDP window?

Tags: windows, winapi, rdp, mstsc

On Windows, is it possible to get some sort of handle or details of a window displayed *inside a RDP session*?

Say you are logged on Machine A, then on there you open a RDP session connecting to Machine B. Is there some code I can run on A that will return the current active window on B?

I'm thinking of something equivalent to Win32.GetForegroundWindow(), but that will work "through RDP", so to speak, so it won't return a handle to the main RDP window, but to the active window *inside* that one.

To be honest, I don't really need a handle, I could probably do with just the window details (position, size etc).

Comment: RDP doesn't know either. It's just remoting the graphics operations. It's like trying to ask your LCD monitor for information about the foreground application.

Comment: In principle, it should be possible to write RDP plugins (or whatever they're called) to do this for you.  But the appropriate code would need to be installed on both A and B.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen, I'm honoured! But I'm slightly puzzled: how does mstsc.exe implement its CTRL-SHIFT-PLUS/MINUS then ? Some undocumented extension to the protocol ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I guess that's how Mstsc.exe is doing it then.

Comment: You may have noticed a program called rdpclip.exe running on the remote system. Guess what that guy does.

Comment: Oh wait, its even simpler. The client just sends an Alt+PrtSc to the remote machine and lets the remote machine take it from there.